# What to use to search for 1 billion text documents?

Tags: search

can tell me  what programming language to use to search for the one billion text documents.
txt file size is 3 kilobytes.What about C++/Java?The search will be carried out only by the names of  txt files.

Thank you all for your answers, I decided to use C + +

Comment: You have not specified the file size!! That will definitely be a very key aspect in that!! Neither you have specified what you are looking to search for?

Comment: file size is 3 kilobytes

Comment: And on what programming language it would be the quickest? I need to search title only txt files

Comment: What about C + + / Java?

Comment: Assembler? But seriously folks, can we quantify "be the quickest". That isn't a realistic requirement.

Comment: @user1790746 How does "full-text-search" relate to "search titles only"? Please clarify/explain the goal and the data *in the post* (edit it).

Comment: Please try to implement it in any language you know, than see if it satisfy your goals. As it stands question is not very good for SO as it asks for discussion on what language is better - [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask).

Comment: But I want that the language that will do it quickly

Comment: That isn't how languages work.  It depends on the efficiency of whatever script or program you write.

Comment: I understand that, I think to do everything in C + +, it works well with the memory, the main thing that I need to have this done quickly

Comment: If you understood that, you wouldn't be asking this question.

Comment: Surely noticed, but I look in favor of C + +

Comment: Thank you all for your answers, I decided to use C + +

Answer (score 2):

A specific language probably isn't the right criterion to use here.

There are many search tools that do wonderful jobs of searching large datasets, which can be utilised by many different programming languages.

[Sphinx](http://sphinxsearch.com/) is one example, which is a search server. You can utilize its indexes in a variety of languages, such as Ruby with [ThinkingSphinx](http://freelancing-god.github.com/ts/en/). [Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/core/) from Apache is another search technology which lends itself to applications written in Java (however there are [.NET](http://lucenenet.apache.org/) and [Ruby](http://ferret.davebalmain.com/) ports of it).

Comment: I would not use other solutions

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you mean searching for a single document out of a billion, you could use nearly every programming language available. Easy choices might be python and java. A more accessible way to do it might just be to use a shell to search, and run a bash command like `sudo find / -name "filename"`.

Comment: And on what programming language it would be the quickest? I need to search title only txt files

Comment: Quickest for you to learn and write: bash script, or a high level language, ie python.
Language that runs the fastest after being written: C/C++ (takes longer to learn and write).

Comment: i know c++,you think to write on it?

Comment: That is the most straightforward answer I can muster. There is A LOT more to it than that. Your question is very vague and isn't relevant to this site.

Comment: please clarify what you mean by "you think to write on it"

Comment: Oh please can help in this matter?

Comment: you think to write it in c + +

Comment: if you know C, write up a program and run it. It should run a bit better and python and higher level languages. The purpose of your goal confuses me and many others here.

Comment: Yes. C. However, if you really wanted to make it as fast as possible, use an assembly language.

Comment: Thanks, by the way then the result of the need to pass on the website, so I choose C or C + + because I do not know assembly language

Comment: Thank you all for your answers, I decided to use C + +